# Gravar objeto em uma list não a referencia

Tags: java, arraylist

O problema é o seguinte tento salvar o objeto em um List e oque acontece é que salva a referencia não o objeto alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

```
ArrayList<ModeloParcela> modeloParcelas = new ArrayList<ModeloParcela>();
for (int i = 1; i < quantidade; i++) {
ModeloParcela modeloParcela = new ModeloParcela();

calendarTemp.add(calendarTemp.MONTH, 1);
System.err.println(result[0]);
modeloParcela.setDataVencimento(calendarTemp);
modeloParcela.setValor(result[0]);      
modeloParcelas.add(retorno(modeloParcela));
}
```

Quando vou mostrar os dados da list vejo que os itens estão todos repetidos.

```
for (ModeloParcela v : modeloParcelas) {                    
System.err.println(format.format(v.getDataVencimento().getTime()));
}
```

Comment: poderia mostrar o método **retorno** ???

Comment: Eu editei e coloquei como estou mostrando os dados.

Comment: Sem saber o que o método retorno faz fica um pouco complicado.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você seta a data de vencimento, (`setDataVencimento` ), você passa a referencia do objeto `Calendar`.

Para evitar isto, utilize o método `clone()`

Neste caso, ele retorna um `Object`, então realizamos um cast:

```
 modeloParcela.setDataVencimento( Calendar.class.cast(calendarTemp.clone()) );
```

Segue a documentação do [clone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()).

Comment: Não deu muito certo aqui não mas obrigado pela dica.

Comment: O que acontece? Poderia mostrar o método **retorno** ?